# Find solutions to linear least square problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, svd, pseudoinverse

> Find all solutions of the linear least squares problem
> $$\min_x\|Ax-b\|_2$$
> where $A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $b = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2\end{matrix}\right]$.

Note that using the SVD of $A = U\Sigma V^T$ we find $A^+$ (the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse) finding $A^+ = V\Sigma^+U^T$, where for $\alpha  \in\mathbb R $, $\alpha^+ =\begin{cases} \alpha^{-1}, &\alpha \ne 0 \\ 0, &\alpha = 0\end{cases}$. Then $A^+ = \left[ \begin{matrix} \frac 14 & \frac 14 \\ \frac 14 & \frac 14 \end{matrix} \right]$.

Then I think it is asking we can find $x = A^+ b = \left[\begin{matrix}  \frac 14 & \frac 14 \\ \frac 14 & \frac 14 \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} \frac 34 \\ \frac 34\end{matrix}\right] $.

Is there more to the question that I am missing?

Comment: Since our system is simultaneously overdetermined and underdetermined, we have infinitely many solutions; take the one you found and add the null space of our operator to it to find the full space of solutions.

Comment: Then would that be some $x = A^+b + (I-A^+A)y$ where $y$ some vector? @user3716267 and then I just evaluate what $I-A^+A) are?

Comment: @user3716267, is that the correct think you were speaking about?

Comment: Yes, though I think there is an easier way of thinking about it than that.  See my full answer below.

Comment: Did you already answer or are you writing it up? @user3716267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that your solution is not unique.

You have found a valid least-squares solution, but note that $A$ has a nontrivial kernel: it takes, for example, $v = (1,-1)$ to $0$.  Accordingly, we can add any element of the kernel to our solution to obtain another valid solution.

It is fairly evident that the kernel of $A$ consists of scalar multiples of the particular $v$ we tried above, so our full solution is

$x + av$

where $x$ is as you have computed, $v$ is as above, and $a$ is some scalar.